# Reference key from same array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to reference the key/value pair of an item in the same array:

```
$glossary_args = array(
    'name'          => 'Glossary Terms',
    'singular_name' => 'Glossary Term',
    'add_new'       => 'Add New Term',
    'edit_item'     => 'Edit Term',
    'search_items'  => 'Search'.$glossary_args["name"],
)
```

Is this even possible? If so, how?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358261/php-self-referencing-array

Comment: Perhaps, but I think that this is a little more specific. In addition to that, I would like to hear opinions on the best way to accomplish this if it is not possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the fact that assignment is itself an expression in PHP:

```
$glossary_args = array(
    'name'          => ($name = 'Glossary Terms'),
    'singular_name' => 'Glossary Term',
    'add_new'       => 'Add New Term',
    'edit_item'     => 'Edit Term',
    'search_items'  => 'Search'.$name
)
```

Comment: Wow, I hoped I could do something like: `functionName($arr = [ 'message' => 'hello', 'something_else' => $arr['message'] ]);` or `functionName([ 'message' => 'hello', 'something_else' => $self['message'] ]);` but yours does work!

Comment: Your PHP kung fu is strong.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this when you're first defining the array - while you're inside `array()`, `$glossary_args` hasn't been created yet. Try this:

```
$glossary_args = array(
  'name' => 'Glossary Terms',
  'singular_name' => 'Glossary Term',
  'add_new' => 'Add New Term',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Term'
);
// first we create the rest of $glossary_args, then we set search_items
$glossary_args['search_items'] = 'Search '.$glossary_args["name"];
```

Comment: Ok. I'm thinking that I will do the same thing that I did with search to add_new and edit_item. The idea is that I would only have to edit name and singular name and it would change the rest of the array. Would you recommend array_push at that point?

Comment: `array_push` can't set array keys, only values. You'd have to set `add_new` and `edit_item` the same way as `search_items`.

Comment: it'd be cleaner to use references . . . see my answer