# How do I access an arraykey of the same array I am currently in?

Tags: php, arrays

I've got the following problem, I'm assigning values to an array, and one of the values I'm trying to assign is dependent on a value from the same array.

Is there a way of doing it somehow LIKE this:

```
# this code throws a notice
$myArray = [
    'keyPairs1' => [
        'color' => 'green',
        '...'   => '...'
    ],
    'keyPairs2' => [
        'value' => $myArray['keyPairs1']['color'] === 'green' ? 'yes' : 'no', # this line
        '...'   => '...'
    ]
];
```

Here PHP throws me a Notice:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: myArray in .../somefile.php on line ...
```

Of course I could simply define the array first and assign something like an empty string to the value and after creating the array simply do

```
$myArray = [
    'keyPairs1' => [
        'color' => 'green',
        '...'   => '...'
    ],
    'keyPairs2' => [
        'value' => '', # this line
        '...'   => '...'
    ]
];

$myArray['keyPairs2']['value'] = $myArray['keyPairs1']['color'] === 'green' ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

but I'd rather keep it all in the array if there is any possible way to do it. The above attempt is obviously not leading to the desired result.

Comment: It's not possible. Create the array in a loop instead of trying to declare it at once.

Comment: I have seen a question like this a few weeks or months ago and it is possible some how. Can't remember how though

Comment: So where does the `green` value come from? Use that in your logic.

Comment: might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358261/php-self-referencing-array, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185545/reference-key-from-same-array