# PHP Array set value as other value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to set a value of a subkey as another value, but when I try to use `$array['Key1']['FullPath']` it returns `Array something`. How can I solve that?
Thanks.

```
$array = Array(
    'Key1' => Array(
        'Path' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
        'FullPath' => ['Path'] . ' something'
    ),
    [...] //another arrays
);
```

Comment: What is this notation supposed to represent? `'FullPath' => ['Path'] . ' something'`

Comment: I want to use "Path" value on "FullPath" key.

Comment: That really doesn't clarify. What is currently in your array, and what are you trying to get out?

Comment: I want to display "http://stackoverflow.com/ something" when `$array['Key1']['FullPath']`

Comment: You can't do what (I think) you're trying to do. In any case, this question is still very unclear.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I'll try to do that.

Comment: Already fixed, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that its possible but i could be wrong , u can do this :

```
$path = 'https://stackoverflow.com/';
$array = Array(
    'Key1' => Array(
        'Path' => $path,
        'FullPath' => $path . ' something'
    ),
    [...] //another arrays
);
```

oh it turn out what u want is possible 
[PHP: Self-referencing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358261/php-self-referencing-array)

Comment: It works, but I don't want value outside the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `Path` is a key, you should change your array struct.

```
$array = array(
 'Key1' => array(
     'Path' => 'http://stackoverflow.com/',
     'FullPath' => array ( 'Path' => '',
                           'Something' => ' something'
)));
```

Comment: I want the value of this key, not as a string

Comment: Already fixed, thanks!!!