# Array Access "this" value

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Is there a way in a PHP array to access an internal value? Much like a `this` in other languages.

I can't think of how that would work or if it is at all possible, but if you consider this layout:

```
$x = [
    "value1" => 1,
    "value2" => THIS.value1 + 1
]
```

Replace `THIS` with the right process to get the previous value. This is how the array would be laid out as well. This is also at the initialization level.

Comment: It’s not possible and you can’t do it in array, object, or dictionary literals in most other languages either.

Comment: Didn't honestly think so... Is there a way you would do something similar in another way??

Comment: You'd have to add `$x['value2'] = $x['value1']+1;` as its own line.

Comment: Not in the same line. Here's a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358261/php-self-referencing-array

Comment: @Paul ... That post is exactly what I was looking for, but didn't know what to search. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$x` (most likely) does not (yet) exist whilst that command is executed. Therefore referencing it does not really make sense...

In short: this is not possible and for good reasons.

---

*If* the array *does* exist before, then this *is* possible obviously:

```
$x = [
    "value1" => 1
];

$x = [
    "value1" => 1,
    "value2" => $x['value1'] + 1
]
```

but I doubt this is what you are looking for :-)

Comment: Sadly it is not! but it is a good answer!