# Include an array key as value for another array value of the same multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to include ALL the values of an index as part of another index's value of the same array, like this: *syntax is wrong*

```
const CONST_ARRAY = array("update"  => "require" . ['c', 'd'],
                          "require" => ['a', 'b']);
```

So that it looks like:

```
const CONST_ARRAY = array("update"  => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                          "require" => ['a', 'b']);
```

Is this possible in PHP or Laravel?

Comment: No, because the array index doesn't exist yet when you are setting the value.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to use values that have not yet been defined.

You need to set `require` values, and next use it. For example:

```
$require = ['a', 'b'];
const CONST_ARRAY = array("update"  => [...$require, 'c', 'd'],
                          "require" => $require);
```

If your PHP version don't support `...`, use `array_merge`

Answer (score 1):

This is ***nearly impossible*** (except by declaring outside like in pablorsk answer) but I found a way:
You will need to use [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) because the `const` syntax will throw an error with this solution. You will also need to declare the referenced array before passing it by reference to [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).
**Working example:**

```
define('CONST_ARRAY', [
    "require" => ($require = ['a', 'b']),
    "update"  => array_merge(($arr = &$require), ['c', 'd'])
]);

// Output
echo '<pre>' . print_r(CONST_ARRAY, true) . '</pre>';
```

This syntax is not so easy to use. I tried with reference *and* spread operator (without success) as:

```
"update"  => [...&$require, 'c', 'd']
```

---

**Note:**
This is probably not something to use in real-life. This answer took help from [PHP: Self-referencing array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358261/php-self-referencing-array#answer-10358470)'s accepted answer.